# is there a way to make a generic if condition to expand my steps easily?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, generics

iam new on React and have a Project where i have to implement a react joyride tour into a finished tool.

currently i have this if condition to check on which page iam, to set the right steps.

```
if (this.props.location.pathname === '/') {
      steps = []
    } else if (this.props.location.pathname === '/matches/' || this.props.location.pathname === '/matches') {
      if (this.props.firstPartClicked === true) {
        steps = matchSiteStepsOne
      } else if (this.props.secondPartClicked === true) {
        steps = matchSiteStepsTwo
      } else {
        steps = matchSiteSteps
      }
    } else if (this.props.location.pathname.startsWith('/matches/') && this.props.location.pathname.endsWith('/edit/') && this.props.location.pathname.match('\\d+')) {
      if (this.props.firstPartClicked === true) {
        steps = matchEditorStepsOne
      } else if (this.props.secondPartClicked === true) {
        steps = matchEditorStepsTwo
      } else {
        steps = matchEditorSteps
      }
    } else if (this.props.location.pathname.startsWith('/matches/') && this.props.location.pathname.includes('sequence')) {
      if (this.props.firstPartClicked === true) {
        steps = matchSequenceStepsOne
      } else if (this.props.secondPartClicked === true) {
        steps = matchSequenceStepsTwo
      } else {
        steps = matchSequenceSteps
      }
    } else if (this.props.location.pathname.startsWith('/matches/') && this.props.location.pathname.match('\\d+')) {
      steps = matchSteps
    }
```

now my question is if is there a way to make it more generic so i can easily expand more steps on different pages, without so much redundant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce redundant code a little by only looking up pathname once, and storing it in a variable as in

```
      pathname = this.props.location.pathname
```

This should make your if statements a bit shorter and easier to read. You could also deduplicate some code if e.g. you replaced matchSiteSteps with matchSteps['Site'], and called a function three times with a body like:

```
if (this.props.firstPartClicked === true) {
        steps = matchStepsOne[type]
      } else if (this.props.secondPartClicked === true) {
        steps = matchStepsTwo[type]
      } else {
        steps = matchSteps[type]
      }
}
```